IRF520 MOSFET won't close when voltage is applied
I'm trying to make a simple MOSFET switch but something weird is happening: no matter the gate input, the LED stays on. Ultimately this circuit is meant to drive a stepper motor but I'm using an LED for a YSWYG approach.
Im using a IRF520 N-Channel MOSFET in the following configuration. As you can see in the following photos, it stays on when connected to either ground or voltage.
Something to note is that, without the pulldown resistor, I can turn the LED on and off by touching the signal with my finger.
For further clarification of the image, the 10 kΩ resistor is connected to 21-23, the LED is 22-5 V, and the 10 Ω resistor 35-23. The MOSFET is 23-21 as GDS.

The power supply board has a 5 V and 3.3 V mode which is set by the jumpers you see on them.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

The LED is lit up like it should be. Now in what configuration it should be off?

What is the YSWYB method?

Looks to me that IRF520 connected 180 degrees wrong orientation. But you are also missing a resistor in series with the LED. You should also control the gate with +5V when you want to switch the circuit off.

@Justme even when connected to ground it is lit!

@Colin You see What You Get ;)

@olltsu isn't Resin forward the right orientation? at least in the datasheet it says so https://www.vishay.com/docs/91017/irf520.pdf
The LED is a 5V white LED!
Either way i already tried the other way around with a 3V3 White LED and also no luck...

@PedroCosta You need to be more specific what do you connect and where to turn it off. Also you might have damaged something, as the LED has no resistor and you have touched the gate so maybe there was ESD to gate.

@Justme the idea is to control a 3V3 stepper motor with a 3V3 2A Power Supply and a DRV8825 and an ESP32... The ESP32 can't provide the desired Amp for the motor thus the need for an external power supply.
My goal is to use 4 Mosfets connected (eac) to A1,A2,B1,B2 (separately) of the DRV8825. Thus making 4 MOSFET switches. The circuit shown above is a simplified version that uses an LED instead of the motor. I did it to test the MOSFETs if they're working properly. shortly after this message i'll try to provide more photos

@PedroCosta That does not explain which wire you intend to connect and where to turn FET off. Please explain or take a picture.

MOSFETs between DRV8825 outputs and the motor is not a solution.

@olltsu turns out you were right... Flipped the MOSFET and it works perfectly... why didn't i try it before asking...

Experience is what you get just after needing it most.


Something to note is that, without the pulldown resistor, i can turn
the LED on and off by touching the signal with my finger...

Yeah, that is quite common and how touch lamps work (old ones anyway), your finger can have thousands of volts on it so it's not hard to provide enough voltage as the FET starts to turn on at ~4.5V. Remember the gate of a mosfet is a capacitor so you can charge it up. One thing you may want to know is that capacitor is only nanometers thick, so by touching it you can blow it out really easy and cause the gate to fail (Vgs can't exceed 20V), which is why it's probably acting erratically.
Put a new fet in, and don't touch the gate unless you can limit the voltage to within ±20V (ESD diode protection).
